# Одновременный запуск android анимации, вместо последовательного

Tags: android, анимация, kotlin

Хочу, чтобы некоторый ImageView сначала переместился направо, потом вниз по нажатию кнопки.
Писал так:

```
    private fun moveX() {
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(beatle, "translationX", getValue(curX)).apply {
            duration = 2000
            start()
        }
    }

    private fun moveY() {
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(beatle, "translationY", getValue(curY)).apply {
            duration = 2000
            start()
        }
    }

    private fun runClick(view: View) {

        while (curX + 1 < WIDTH) {
            curX++
            moveX()
        }

        while (curY + 1 < HEIGHT) {
            curY++
            moveY()
        }
    }
```

еще пытался так:

```
beatle.animate().translationX(getValue(x)).translationY(getValue(y)).setDuration(2000).start()
```

В обоих случаях вместо того чтобы последовательно пойти вправо и вниз, моя картинка шла по диагонали, выполняя эти команды одновременно. Можно ли используя эти классы написать последовательную анимацию? Если нет, то что мне использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде, вы отдаёте запрос на анимацию, но так как она выполняется долго, управление часто возвращается обратно в поток, поэтому и получается, что запускается сразу 2 анмиации. Вам нужно дождаться когда закончится одна и только тогда начинать другую.

Попробуйте так:

```
beatle
  .animate()
  .translationX(getValue(x))
  .setDuration(2000)
  .withEndAction({
      beatle
        .animate()
        .translationY(getValue(y))
        .setDuration(2000)
        .start()
  })
  .start()
```

Comment: спасибо, ваше решение действительно решает проблему, которую я описал(для 2 последовательных команд). Можно ли как-то сделать последовательную анимацию для произвольного количества команд?

Comment: ну также цепочкой

Comment: либо создавать поток, который слушает, что пришла его очередь, а в методе withEndAction выставлять флаг

Comment: Снова спасибо. Я, наверное, неправильно понял слово "поток", но мое решение использовало очередь(дек), куда я складывал все нужные анимации, которые потом запускал рекурсивно. Получилось какое-то оффлайн решение.